# How to correctly only allow quantities of 5 in business part ledger

Tags: java, modulo

I'm a second-year college student so I want to stick to the basics. I have to make a business part ledger using a switch, and some parts require to be ordered in groups of 5. I know there's a better way of doing this since what I currently have does not correctly round up to the closest 5. Any help making this code more efficient would be amazing since I know there's a lot of issues, thanks!

```java
        System.out.println("enter a part");
        String part = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter a quantity");
        int quant = scan.nextInt();

         int b = 5;
         int c = quant % 5;

            switch(part) {

            case "1":
                p += 1 * quant; 

            case "5":
                System.out.println("would you like to upgrade? 1 for yes, 2 for no");
                int yn = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println(yn);

                if (yn == 1) {
                    p += 10000;
                } else if (yn == 2) {
                    p += 7;
                }

                p *= quant;


                break;

            case "6":
                 if (c == 0) {
                     p+=3;
                 } else if (quant >= 5) {
                    b -= quant;
                    quant += b;
                     p+=3;
                } else if (quant <= 5) {
                    b += quant;
                    quant -= b;
                     p+=3;
                }

                break;
```